# Can css3 "flex box" layout absorb extra space in both direction?

Tags: flexbox

I know "flex" propery could make flex item absorb extra spaces in one direction (if the "flex-direction" value is "row", the extra space in the row will be absorbed.)

But what if I wrap these items? The items in the second line just absorb extra spaces in second line. However, they will not absorb the space in vertical direction if any.

Maybe the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stg609/farpK/3/) could make you understand me more clearly.

```
.container {
    display:-webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow:row wrap;
    width: 350px; /*just for demo, it should be the same width as the browser*/
}
.item {
    width:100px; /*All these items have the same width*/
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid;
    margin:5px;
}
.item:nth-child(even) {
    height:100px;
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 3</div>
    <div class="item">Item 4</div>
    <div class="item">Item 5</div>
</div>
```

I hope the item5 could immediately after the item2. There's no extra spaces except the margin one.

Can someone help me figure it out?

Comment: Your question at the end is missing a few words, making it difficult to decipher what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

By default flex items want to stretch along the *cross axis* (which is vertical for the *row* direction) thanks to the default value of `align-items: stretch` on flex containers.  However, if the flex item has an explicit height, it overrides the stretchiness.

http://jsfiddle.net/farpK/5/

If I change both `height` properties to `min-height`, they begin stretching as they should.

Comment: Thanks. But the height here is just for the demo. It cannot be changed in production environment.

Comment: Finally, I gave up using the native flex features. I make use of js to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i am making a layout (desktop screen only) completely in flexbox

```
   * {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family: arial;
    color: #333;
}
html {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #111;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #dedede;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
body > header, footer {
    min-height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
body > #body {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
body > #body > nav, aside {
    flex: 1 1 15%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
body > #body > #content {
    flex: 1 1 70%;
}
body > #body > nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
body > #body > nav > #userLinks {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
body > #body > nav > #userLinks a {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    color: blue;
    margin-left: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    margin-right: 9px;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-decoration: none;
}
body > #body > nav > #userLinks a:hover {
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
    color: #e2e2e2;
}
body > #body > nav > #userLinks a img {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #eee;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    border: 0;
    margin-right: 9px;
}
body > #body > nav > #todoAppContainer {
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
body > #body > nav > #todoAppContainer:before {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%;
    /* initial ratio of 1:1*/
}
body > #body > nav > #todoAppContainer >#todoApp {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
#notifications {
    background-color: #cbcbcb;
    height: 64px;
}
#communications {
    background-color: #cacaca;
    height: 128px;
}
#messageBox {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/max1979/6T226/2/

Lemme kno